# Fixed Background in Print CSS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, printing, media-queries

Is there any way to have a background image fixed to a print media query on scroll?

I want to use it for a web-to-print solution. Every page that is printed should contain the A4 background with the logo and some design stuff on it.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What does scrolling have to do with anything? You can't scroll a printed document... Also providing a bit of background around what you've tried would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to have the same background on each page regardless of how many pages print.

If that's the case you can use the special `@page` rule to specify how all printed pages should work. This is part of the [Paged Media Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/).

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0.25in;
  background: top left URL('myimg.png') no-repeat;
}
```

However, **most browsers default to NOT printing background images**.

Sometimes you can defeat this default by using [`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) but be aware this is non-standard and only works in webkit browsers.

A better solution (if the image is absolutely integral to the printed output) might be to absolute position an `<img>` on each page and then use `z-index` to position it behind the other content.